# CodeIgniter remove index.php apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm using CodeIgniter on a Windows machine using the Zend Comunity Server with apache. My apache is properly configured to handle .htaccess directives and mod_rewrite is enabled (httpd.conf):

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride FileInfo
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

My root is `C:\www\` and my site is located in `C:\www\david\` and when I type `http://localhost/david/`, the index.php is loaded along with the correct controller. I want to access my things directly through `http://localhost/david/Articles/` instead of `http://localhost/david/index.php/Articles/`. To do this I have to use apache rewrite module.

To do so, I've placed a `.htaccess`file in the `C:\www\david\` folder. This file contains code I found on [here](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/) :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /david/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^core.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I made a couple of changes to the code since my configuration is a bit different from the default. I'm not on the root so : 'RewriteBase /davidfrancoeur.com/' and I've renamed the CodeIgniter system folder for additional security so : 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^core.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

With this done, anything should work properly, I should be able to access `http://localhost/david/Articles/` without a problem and I think I shouldn't be able to reach `http://localhost/david/core/config/config.php` directly.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, it doesn't even look like any rewriting is done. Do you see if I'm doing something wrong here? Is there a way to know if apache actually rewrite anything?

Thanks a lot. And yes I looked at the millions of article I could found about this... :(

**EDIT**

CI 2.0.2, PHP 5.3, Apache 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking carefully into the httpd.conf of my Zend Community Server, I realized that there was two `<Directory />`instruction. The first one was empty as shown in the question and the second one looked like that :

```
<Directory "C:\Dropbox\www">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None
    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I changed the following line `AllowOverride None` to AllowOverride All` and it worked. For those who would like to know more about URL rewrite with CodeIgniter look there : http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/

And to understand properly what `AllowOverride`does read : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Thanks again to ever helped!

Answer (score 3):

It will work.....actually your first two rewrite conditions and rules are working but in third rewrite condition you are allowing user to access request file ,even if it is core or system file.

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^core.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Edit: Fixed 'rewrite' typo

Comment: I still can access the core folder, app and sys folder are shown.

Answer (score 0):

ppet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

```
#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```