# Remove Controller from every url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have searched everywhere but i can't find appropriate result. I want to remove controller_name from every url of the site. My codeigniter is installed in subfolder of domain.

For Example:

```
www.site_name.com/subfolder/controller_name/any_method_name
```

I have only one controller from which i am calling all the methods.

I have learned that i have to do some changes in routes but i think that is only for one url. so, how to remove for every url.

Comment: look that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748234/codeigniter-remove-index-php-apache-mod-rewrite

Comment: Thanks for your help, all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works but you could try adding this in your `application\config\routes.php`:

```
$route['([a-z]+)'] = 'controller_name/$1';
```

The documentation https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#regular-expressions

Comment: No, Its not working but i think this may be happen because i have installed my codeigniter in subfolder.

Comment: Other thing is, will it work for url which is redirecting from some other page?

Comment: Pratik Bhalodiya answer should work out in your case

Answer (score 0):

Here, I am answering my own question. I have solved this problem by following solution.

Suppose, my controller name is **users**, then the answer is:

```
$route['^(:any)(/:any)?$'] = "users/$0";
```

This removes controller name from every url of the website.

Comment: that may give problem when site will in sub domain or sub folder

Answer (score -1):

Codeigniter support two types of routing rules

1)Wildcards

2)Regular Expressions

I prefer Wildcards

in routes just place this one

$route['login/(:any)'] = "v1/login";

A URL with "login" as the first segment, and anything in the second will be remapped to the "v1" class and the "login" method.

means your change www.abc.com/login instead of www.abc.com/v1/login

check it once routing in codeigniter here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html .......